# How fast can we walk?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, rotational-dynamics, everyday-life, oscillators

It has been a common observation that as and when we accelerate ourselves, there comes a point after which we cannot stay on the ground completely. I wanted to know whether we can find such a maximum speed for any person, perhaps by assuming an average person is 2 metres tall? By maximum speed i try to mean the fastest we can walk before we get running.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racewalking

Comment: Average height of 2 metres? There is no local population with an average that large.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about biomechanics, not physics.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Biomechanics is a part of biophysics is it not? I took a class offered by my physics department where two weeks were devoted to looking at some pretty in-depth things about the physics of walking/running.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty I think It probably has to do with both biomechanics and physics.

Comment: U guys are akrot

Answer (score 2):

Interesting question. Somehow I think it may be more related to how long a stride one can take without having both feet off the ground. That may have more to do with how long ones legs are, than how tall one is, though I'm not sure.

Once your stride is maximized, in order to increase your horizontal displacement per unit time you may have to exert a vertical "push" off the ground that results in both feet off the ground for some time interval.

Not sure if this answers your question but perhaps it advances the analysis.

In any case, hope this helps.